# can't install jar in mobile phone (CLDC and MIDP)

Tags: java-me, midp, cldc

When I export a jar of my j2me code I can install it on an emulator but not on my mobile phone with the error :

> Not Supported

But I can install others jar from net on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

There are some phones that will only let you install MIDlets OTA.
OTA = Over The Air
Basically just means that you HAVE to put your JAR and JAD file online, and then install from an URL that points to the JAD file.
When doing this, it is also important that MIME-types for JAD and JAR files are set correctly on the web-server.

Comment: on  nokia 6700  it asks only where to save even via OTA.  Why its so, before there wasnt problems on old phones?  I just OKed file in filebrowsers and that initialized all installations.

Comment: This is most likely because your webserver isn't setup with correct mime-types for JAR and JAD files.

Comment: Sorry,  that was funny , "nokia 6700 Dual SIM" just doesnt support Java.My fault.

Comment: Weird. Nokia 6700 Classic seems to support Java (according to GSM arena), but it does appear that Nokia 6700 Slide doesn't. Makes no sense.
https://www.gsmarena.com/nokia_6700_classic-2659.php

Comment: not slide or classic , to be more specific, I'm talking about this kind https://www.made-in-china.com/showroom/poseitech/product-detailieGEwvPAZCVW/China-6700-Dual-SIM-Mobile-Phone.html 

of 6700. At bottom in "Product Description" you can see it shows the Java's support as "no".